# How to write to a file in sml

Tags: sml

I'm trying to write a string to a file, however I cant seem to get it working, I've read though all the questions like this on stack overflow but none seem to be addressing the issue. I'm from an imperative background so usually I would, write to file, then close the output stream... However this doest work in sml.

```
fun printToFile pathOfFile str = printToOutstream (TextIO.openOut pathOfFile) str;

//Here is where the issues start coming in

fun printToOutStream outstream str = TextIO.output (outstream, str)
                                     TextIO.closeOut outstream
//will not work. I've also tried

fun printToOutStream outstream str = let val os = outStream
                                     in
                                       TextIO.output(os,str)
                                       TextIO.closeOut os
                                     end;
//also wont work.
```

I know I need to write to the file and close the output stream but I cant figure out how to do it. Using my "sml brain" I'm telling myself I need to call the function recursively stepping towards something and then when I reach it close the output stream... but again I don't have a clue how I would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always read/write complete files at once, you could create some helper functions for this, like:

```
fun readFile filename =
    let val fd = TextIO.openIn filename
        val content = TextIO.inputAll fd handle e => (TextIO.closeIn fd; raise e)
        val _ = TextIO.closeIn fd
    in content end

fun writeFile filename content =
    let val fd = TextIO.openOut filename
        val _ = TextIO.output (fd, content) handle e => (TextIO.closeOut fd; raise e)
        val _ = TextIO.closeOut fd
    in () end
```

Comment: This is nice and deserves to be the accepted answer. I wanted to show OP how close they were to having a working solution, but your answer is more complete. It does make sense to wrap opening and closing the file in 1 function.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. Between the `in` and `end` you need to delimit the expressions by the semicolon. In SML `;` is a sequence-operator. It evaluates expressions in turn and then only returns the value of the last one.

If you already have an outstream open, use:

```
fun printToOutStream outstream str = let val os = outstream
                                     in
                                       TextIO.output(os,str);
                                       TextIO.closeOut os
                                     end;
```

Used like thus:

```
- val os = TextIO.openOut "C:/programs/testfile.txt";
val os = - : TextIO.outstream
- printToOutStream os "Hello SML IO";
val it = () : unit
```

Then when I go to "C:/programs" I see a brand new text file that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I mistakenly thought that writing a semi-colon and then pressing enter evaluates everything previously so I avoided it.

Comment: I think of semicolons as being side-effect triggers. In the REPL you want the side effect of evaluating and printing the expression -- so you end the expression with a semicolon. When dealing with IO you are using the side-effect heavy part of ML where you want expression to be evaluated for their side effects, hence you tend to need a fair amount of semicolons. As a rule of thumb -- if something has the flavor of a statement in an imperative language rather than a function definition in a functional language, you probably should use a semicolon.

Comment: @James: You can think differently of the semicolon between declarations (being a convenience for effectuating something in the REPL and being largely optional) and the semicolon inside expressions, being much more alike an actual binary operator, even though you can't overload it. You know you have the latter and not the former when your semicolon is either enclosed in parentheses, e.g. `(print "ok\n"; f x)`, or inside a let-expression, e.g. `let ... in print "ok\n"; f x end`.